# RabbitMQ and Hibernate: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rabbitmq

I am trying to develop a small Springboot application (using JHipster) that listens to a RabbitMQ queue, acknowledges the messages and then runs some operations on a hibernate repository. For now I can consume messages with no problem. But when I try to use the hibernate repository when receiving a message, it appears the TransactionManagers get mixed up and I get the Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:282)
 ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.commit(PgConnection.java:872)
```

My Rabbit configuration is simplistic:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitExchangeConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("myQueue", false);
    }
}
```

Then there is my TestService, with a RabbitListener (**listen**) and a method that uses my database transaction manager to access the repository (**test**)

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    public TestService(
        MyRepository myRepository
    ) {
        this.myRepository= myRepository;
    }

    // My Listener to receive the messages
    @RabbitListener(queues = "datafactory")
    public void listen(Message in) {
        String messageBody = new String(in.getBody());       
        test(messageBody);
    }

    // the method that should do stuff with the repository
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "myDatabaseTransactionManager")
    public void test(String content) {
        myRepository.findById(content).orElse(null);
        ..
    }
}
```

Right now I don't care what the message contains, nor is it important if the entity can be found.

When I comment out the call to `test(content)` then the message is received (I can see it in the logs). But when I try to call the function, then I get the Exception.

Is there any way to end the RabbitMQ-transaction before entering the hibernate transaction context? Why is the listener trying to use the hibernate transaction?

## solved

Thanks to the [answer of p3consulting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75023305/896249)  I found that `jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true`  was set by default. It was configuered automatically by JHipster for me. I just had to make sure that autocommit was disabled for good:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false  // disables auto commit
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=false   // makes sure it stays that way
```

So nothing to do with RabbitMQ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is clear: you left autocommit to TRUE then you can't commit explicitly because it's done for you after each DML statement, you could turn it off with `hibernate.connection.autocommit=false` in your properties or calling `connection.setAutoCommit(false);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I set it to `false` (althoughm the Hikari connection was already set to `autocommit: false`. It didn't solve the problem, just the error message is different: `JpaSystemException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection;` It looks like the AMQP listener is trying to use the JDBC transaction. Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: Not from the code and the stacktrace you show here. Do you see any method related to AMQP in the stacktrace?

Comment: You where right, the stacktrace was related to amqp only because the Exception was thrown during the execution of the listener method. I tested my database setup with a different approach and saw that `jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true` was set by default. A simple  `provider_disables_autocommit=false` solved my problem.